# Inverse of IN in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I feel foolish, but I cannot find the answer to this.

If I have a User with many attributes, given a list of attributes, I can ask rails something like this:

```
User.where("attributes.id IN ?", list_of_attribute_ids)
```

With the appropriate joins or includes or whatever.

However, I have no idea how to find the inverse set of those users. That is, given 100 users, if the result return 75 entries, I don't know how to find the other 25!

I thought

```
User.where("attributes.id NOT IN ?", list_of_attribute_ids)
```

might work (similarly, User.where.not), but it doesn't! Instead, it looks for those users where *any of their attributes are not one of the list*, which is useful, but not what I want.

The only way I know how to do it, is with something like:

```
User.where.not(id: User.where("attributes.id IN ?", list_of_attribute_ids).pluck(:id))
```

Which is sort of like the SQL for select user where id not in (gather a list of ids).

But this is **massively** non-performant, and generally just can't cope with a database with more than a few (hundred) entries.

How do you do this?

Comment: So, the proper "inverse" of your first statement is all users minus those who match the first statement. Depending on your exact needs, several approaches are possible. If you need both sets at the same time, you can just read the whole dataset, then fetch only the ids of matching users (with attributes) and split/group them in the app. Or you can do that last query of yours.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins this might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use left outer joins, like @Vishal mentioned in the comments.

See the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins

rails 4:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN <something>")
```

rails 5:

```
left_outer_joins(:something)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have now learnt that it's a left outer join. In rails 5 there's a left_outer_join method, but in <=4, I got the job done with something like User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOINS attributes ON attributes.id in ?", list_of_attribute_ids).where("attributes IS NULL"). The key being that a left outer join still keeps those records where there is no association. will_paginate threw up some issues, so I don't have a solution to my full problem yet, but this is the answer to this problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: Avoid comments like thanks. Hah - thanks @RaVeN. Sorry SO